# Tracking a Link Click in Classic Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm in the process of learning event tracking in Classic Google Analytics. I was just wondering if this code was all I would need to track how many times this link was clicked (This is just an example):

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'link', 'click', 'https://www.google.com/',, false]);">Google</a>
```

Besides creating the event tracking goal in analytics. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you also need the GA library.. and I would suggest you implement the newer Universal Analytics tag and syntax instead.

Comment: Is the GA library just the initial code you put on the page that's provided from analytics? Also would I be able to use the universal analytics tag If my GA library is from the Classic Analytics?

Comment: the two libraries have different syntax and are not interchangeable. My advice is to use the UA library because it's Google's newer version and the classic one is deprecated.

Comment: And yes, it's the initial code snippet you add to all your pages, found in Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code

Comment: Awesome! So I'll be able to track the clicks on the link with just the code above. Thank you for your help!